# Create an array or list from text file and store values in labels (VB.net)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
Andrew Law
32
6'1
123 Pounds
Tom Harris
19
5'5 
180 Pounds
Randy Poffo
45
5'3
141 Pounds
```

Now on my form i have a listbox and four labels.

What i would like to do is have the listbox show only the names of the people in the text file (Andrew Law, Tom Harris, Randy Poffo) and when the user clicks the persons name in the listbox i would like each of the labels to show the corresponding details for that person (one label showing age, one showing their height and one showing their weight.)

I'm aware i could do this with a database however i would much prefer doing it by creating an array or list.

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Comment: You need to get the ball rolling yourself and then post here when you encounter an actual issue.  SO is a place to get help with specific issues in code you are writing, not a place for people to show or teach you how to do things from scratch. The first step here is reading the file and there is LOADS of information out there about reading text files so you haven't actually encountered an issue yet if you haven't read that information and tried to put it into practice.

Comment: Just look up how to read a text file and it will all become clear from there